# How to select the number of filters in CNN

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm tweaking the architecture of my CNN to increase the performance on the CIFAR-10 dataset.

While setting most of the hyper-parameters is more or less straightforward, selecting the number of filters for each layer seems ambiguous.

What is the right framework / intuition to set # of filters to begin with and the # of filters for the following layers in a CNN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct method to know the number of filters to use for your model. However you can test some values like 16,32,64,128,256...

There is an idea to do automate this process that I use for finding the right number of convolution layers and filters for the neural network.

```
conv_layers = [3, 4, 5]
units = [32,64,128]

for conv_layer in conv_layers:
    for unit in units:
        Name = "CNN-LSTM-{}convl--{}LSTM-{}-time".format(conv_layer,unit,int(time.time()))
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Input(shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3)))
        model.add(Reshape(target_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH * 3)))
        model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation='relu',
                         input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH * 3), data_format='channels_last'))
        for i in range(conv_layer-1):
            model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))

        model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation='relu'))
        model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation='relu'))
        model.add(LSTM(unit, activation='relu'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
        model.build(input_shape=(batch_size, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3))
        model.summary()
```

After training, you can use [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard) to visualize your results and choose the best architecture that suits your data.

This may take more time in training, so think at saving the models while your training process.

I hope this helps you.